# Regular expression for last name

Tags: regex, groovy

I need a regex for last names. Should start with alphabets. Can have a space, `-` or `'` in the name, but cannot begin with it. 
Cannot have numbers either in the name.
So far I have this:

```
 /^[A-Za-z]+([\'\s-]?[A-Za-z]+)$/
```

It fails for 'test\nThis', 'test\rThis', 'test\tThis' and 'test\fThis'

Any ideas how these last names should not be allowed ?

Thanks

Comment: I think the only way to tell if its a last name is to use a combination of a dictionary of common names that are not contained in an ordinary dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about names like:
 Martin d'Arras
 Martin Luther King, Jr.

Try this -

/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i

Comment: Your expression doesn't have to start with an alpha

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 ^[A-Za-z](( )?[A-Za-z'-]( )?)+$
```